# Swift4: Calendar gives me wrong value for secondsFromGMT

Tags: ios, swift

For my iOS App I need some calculations for Dates and Time. By using the class Calendar I found out, that this class gives me some wrong values for dates in the 19th century and before. During this time, the time zones in Europe were very unstructured. For example, GMT+0:53:28. The class Calendar knows about this and shows me the correct time zone. But the return value of "secondsFromGMT" is wrong: 3600 seconds in this case. Does anyone have some experience with this error or with related problems?

```
import Foundation

let timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Berlin")
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = timeZone!

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en-US")

let date = formatter.date(from: "01.07.1622 08:10:00")!

formatter.dateStyle = .long
formatter.timeStyle = .long

let stringDate = formatter.string(from: date)
let offsetFromGMT = calendar.timeZone.secondsFromGMT(for: date)
print(stringDate, "  Offset =", offsetFromGMT)
```

July 1, 1622 at 8:10:00 AM GMT+0:53:28   Offset = 3600

Comment: I have no idea why this is downvoted or considered "unclear" – The formatted date has a GMT offset of "+0:53:28", but secondsFromGMT() returns 3600. It *could* be that the calendar routines just do not work so far in the past, but this is a clear and reproducible problem description.

Comment: I c/p your code and in test for OSX, I breakpointed at the end and got strange results that could give you some leads. Got "July 1, 1622 at 8:10:00 AM GMT+0:09:21   Offset = 3600" for the print. Then `po formatter.timeZone?.secondsFromGMT(for: date)` make it works (got "561") on my  side. But strangely not for `po timeZone?.secondsFromGMT(for: date)` (got "3600"). And according to the print `calendar.timeZone.secondsFromGMT()` neither Could it be "reference" struct/class in Swift issues?

Comment: Parsing the date in GMT and Europe/Berlin and then getting interval between them yields the correct result `3208.0 secs`.

Comment: I wonder whether `timeZone.secondsFromGMT` really checks historical dates because it doesn't really now about calendar. Maybe it only checks for daylight saving time?

Comment: Thanks for the help and your comments. I'm dived a little bit deeper in the world of time zones. Time zones should have an algorithm for calculating daylight saving in the future and a list of historical events (for example daylight saving during World War I in 1916-1918). It is interesting that DateFormatter works correct, but TimeZone contains errors. This can only be explained if Apple has implemented the same task twice. If so, then it's a terrible software architecture. By the way, with the time zone "Europe / Paris" it works correctly.